# How to paste in a new line with sublime text 3?

Tags: sublimetext3

For example when i put the cursor at the beginning of the line and paste in this code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
```

i want my pasted text to appear like this

```
pasted text
<script type="text/javascript">
```

Answer (score 1):

I think only **line copy** works in your favor.

If you want to copy only a specific portion of text, where you make a text-selection and hit `ctrl + c` - that's just copying the *text-selection*.
When you paste, it's just the copied characters (text-selection). It doesn't copy an entire **line**.

On the other hand, if you **line copy** (which I guess is useful while coding where you are more likely to copy-paste an entire line of code), it shall work as you described.

To do that -> simply press `ctrl + c` with the cursor anywhere on the line you wish to copy(***no text-selection please***) and hit `ctrl + v` with the cursor anywhere on the target line.

The **copied line** will get pasted right above your **target line**.