# vim copy to clipboard with extra newline

Tags: vim

In order to copy to clipboard, I use `"+y` but one small thing is bugging me: if I copy it to some other program, like Sublime Text, sublime it entering to new line after i copy it.

For example, I have the following text:

```
this is sentences from vim
```

and I only select:

```
this is sentences
```

in visual mode then I press `"+y`.

When I paste in Sublime Text, I get a new line after it:

```
this is sentences
<this is where my cursor at>
```

Why does this happen? How do I prevent Vim from adding that newline when copying?

Comment: https://vi.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Define "visual mode".

Comment: Visual mode or normal mode allows you to perform editing tasks on selected portions of text.

Answer (score 0):

[How to paste in a new line with sublime text 3?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54782504/19373717)

this is somewhat similar; it shows that when you paste after 'line copying'
into Sublime, it will paste above your currently targeted line.

i.e. vim isn't adding a new line, Sublime is just pasting above your currently selected line